# Linq query returns all rows when search has no matching results

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following query, problem is it returns all results if no match is found. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
var searchResults = (from gId in dc.tbl1
    join data in dc.tbl2 on gId.ID equals data.UserId into joinTbls
    from data in joinTbls.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where  (data.OrderId == orderId) ||
        (data.CardHolderName == cardHolderName) ||
        (gId.Email == emailAddress) ||
        (gId.FirstName == firstName) ||
        (gId.LastName == lastName) ||
        ((IdGuid == null || gId.ID == IdGuid))
```

I think it has something to do with:

```
from data in joinTbls.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Did you try removing DefaultIfEmpty() ?

Comment: IMO it's because you have "OR" (||) in your Where clause. try to replace it with "AND" (&&)

Comment: Yes, but that then only returns records from tbl1

Comment: The way the table structure is, someone can make a free purchase or paid purchase, free purchase has no match in tbl2

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson then you shouldn't receive any result. because you are making a join on "gId.ID equals data.UserId", LINQ will generate the SQL with mapping those 2 tables, and everything from table 1 which is not registered in table 2 simple would be avoided because of join.
you need  [Left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) instead of "join"

Comment: Thanks @BMaximus your suggestion help solve the problem. I stored all the search parameters in an array, then searched on the array name. This solved my problem. (where data.OrderId     == queryText
                                                             || data.CardHolderName == queryText
                                                             || gId.Email           == queryText
                                                             || gId.FirstName       == queryText
                                                             || gId.LastName        == queryText)

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson you welcome)))

Comment: @GeorgePhillipson The DefaultIfEmpty() is a left loin if you do not want that remove it...

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's because you have "OR" ( || ) in your Where clause. try to replace it with "AND" (&&)

Glad it helped